# msbuild + visual studio executing the wrong typescript version despite installing from nuget

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have installed the typescript compiler, and MSBUILD into the project.
It's a **dotnet core project** (csproj) targeting framework 4.6.1

```
`.csproj file...`
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  <AssemblyName>Ignite.Web</AssemblyName>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <PackageId>Ignite.Web</PackageId>
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\Ignite.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\net461\Ignite.Web.xml</DocumentationFile>
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\Ignite.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
...
```

The file also contains the nuget packages for compiler and msbuild

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler" Version="2.3.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="2.3.3" />
```

Yet when I build using visual studio 2017, or msbuild I get errors because the wrong version of the compiler is being used.

How do I either **suppress building typescript in the IDE and msbuild altogether** (I am using webpack anyway), or **fix the path**?

```
PreComputeCompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe --project "C:\Projects\Github\Ignite\Ignite.Web\tsconfig.json" --listEmitted
  Files
CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2\tsc.exe --project "C:\Projects\Github\Ignite\Ignite.Web\tsconfig.json" --listEmitted
  Files
```

as I can see from the output, it's using the 2.2 version when I execute msbuild.

Comment: btw why do you include those NuGet packages if you want the TS compile to be done via WebPack? I'd assume the compiler would then be pulled in via npm

Comment: I use visual studio to edit the typescript files, and it's useful having the errors / warnings shown in the IDE, I am not sure how I would do that otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imported targets included in VS allow the compilation to be disabled by using

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

in the `csproj` file.

To coerce the typescript compiler to use the included 2.3 version of the `Microsoft.Typescript.Compiler` use

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

in the `csproj` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case, we want VS to compile TypeScript during the build. Do I need to update the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> to, say, 3.3, if I update the nuget package to version (say) 3.3.1?